# Get First Image From PHP Pages With PHP

Tags: php, html, web

I am writing a PHP script to iterate through a directory of PHP web pages and pull out the first image from each of those pages and print HTML for the image. I get an error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in MYPC\scripts\summary.php on line 27

Iterate through directory:

```
$dir = 'posts/*';
foreach(glob($dir) as $file) {
    $contents = file_get_contents($file);
    page_title($file);
    summarise($contents);
    catch_that_image($file);
}
```

Find first image (part with error):

```
function catch_that_image( $str ) {  
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $str, $matches);  
    echo $matches[1][0];  
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the DOM to get the image?

Comment: I'm still pretty new to PHP - could you point me in the right direction to using the DOM to get the image?

Comment: `$dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->loadHTMLFile($yourFile); $imageNode = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);` See the mqanual for more info http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php